# How to detect which parent layout component currently active in Angular in app.component?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to check which layout component currently active in Angular in app.component ?

Here Is example my app-routing.module.ts.

```
{
        path: '',
        component: FrontComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'login',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'message-list',
                component: MessageListComponent,
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now I want to check layout component in app.component such as if it is '**FrontComponent**' or '**MainComponent**' . Because I want to perform some activity based on layout component. I have searched other questions but could not get required answer. can anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance.
Specifically looking to check layout frontcomponent is active in app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn it by looking at the URL with

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    template: ''
})
export class Component {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if ( this.router.url.indexOf('login') != -1) {
          console.log('Father is FrontComponent');
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your idea is good for less number of path used in layout component but I am having more no of path in 'FrontComponent ' layout with 12-15 paths. Specifically my requirement is to check whether layout component is 'FrontComponent'

Comment: OK....getting above idea I have used in a way that  created array of all paths belongs to FrontComponent and then getting path from location.pathname.split('/') , I am checking from that array. So now its working. Thanks Oded BD.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service where you store the current layout component name string, and this variable gets overridden when switching to the other component.